# Lock gmail access from a smartphone

Tags: gmail, smartphone

A friend has broken his smartphone. It has (at least) three security issues:

- It is not protected by any PIN, password or fingerprint
- It automaticaly access gmail (I'm not sure if he just rememberd the password in the browser or if in some way, gmail knows the object itself via some kind on token)
- gmail contains tons of unencrypted passwords and ways to retreive almost every passwords.

In summary: My friend's privacy is open bar from that smartphone (and by the way also my privacy since I send him many emails).

Now it is broken. He is hesitating about making fix it in a shop: at the moment the smartphone is working, the reparator has access to everything.

Questions:

- what to do to revoke the access to gmail from the smartphone when we don't have access to it ? (it is broken)
- what other security issue do I have to fear from leaving that smartphone in unkonwn hand for a couple of days ?

Comment: 1)If you have a password remembered than you can use remote logout and changing the password functionality to protect you email from unauthorized access
2) Now a days phone contains a lot of sensitive data in it so there is a security issue in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do, if you cannot use the phone, is to simply change the Gmail password and unlink the device from your Google account.

If you can use your phone, the easiest thing is to save everything on the phone and do a factory reset before handing to someone else.